# Making a object rotate in & out smoothly

Tags: math, rotation

I'm having trouble, I've searched and studied but I just can't figure this out.

I'm making a space game and want to have the player orient the ship and have the ship smoothly rotate in & out. So the ship's rotation speed will increase then decrease so it won't over shoot it's goal.

I've looked up SUVAT and the sort but I just can't make a go of it.

The values I have to work with are

- The ship's angle
- The ship's desired angle
- The ship's rotation speed
- The rate the ship's rotation speed can increase

So if the ship was at angle 0 and want to orient to angle 90, it would increase it's rotation speed until angle 45 at which it would start to decrease it's rotation speed so when it hits angle 90 the rotation speed will be stopped.

I should note that the rotation speed can be positive or negative depending on which way the ship needs to rotate (Clockwise/counterclockwise)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you talking about in-plane 2D rotation or rotation in 3D about an arbitrary axis?  And what do you mean by "rotate in & out smoothly"?  Do you mean starting and stopping rotation smoothly?

Comment: It's a 2d game. And I mean, the ship can rotate at 10 degrees a second, but it wouldn't start at 10 degress a second but slowly accelerate that speed. (the deccelerate so it would make an instant stop)

Answer (score 0):

The ship's rotation rate would increase half the time, and decrease the other half time.
You could first determine the halfway point: `half = abs(desiredAngle - startAngle)`. (The absolute value allows this to work for both positive and negative values) Calculate this before you start rotating. Then, in your update loop, calculate how much you have rotated: `currentChange = abs(currentAngle - startAngle);` To calculate rotation speed, `rotationSpeed += (currentChange > half) ? -rate : rate;` However, using this method, you may slightly under or over shoot the desired angle. To fix this, check if you are within a certain  (small) threshold of the final angle, and then just set the current angle to the desired angle, and the rotation speed to zero.

Comment: I thought about that, but what if the player changes the angle while the ship is rotating. Would this method still work?

Comment: Do you mean if the player changes the target angle? Then you would have to recalculate `half`, with the same start angle, but new `desiredAngle`. The method should still work, though.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a maximum at which the ship rotation speed can decrease/increase, you cannot prevent overshooting a target set by the player if she changes her target while still moving towards another target. What you *can* do, however, is ensure that you adapt your current speed in such a manner that you reach the final goal at zero speed (i.e. without overshooting) as fast as possible. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_control for a general method for solving *optimal control* problems. Optimal control typically involves accelerating/decellerating at full-thrust always (until the target is reached).

To solve the problem, denote the current angle at the moment a new command is given by C, and the target angle by T. Angular speed at the moment the new target is received is denoted by V', max acceleration will be denoted by M. Positive V corresponds to rotating clockwise, negative V with moving counterclockwise.

Say your initial angular speed is bigger than 0 (V'>0), then there are two possibilities to reach T:

1) increase V for a period U, and then decrease it until it is zero. Then your final angle will be (draw a picture of velocity vs time, and determine it's area to verify):

```
C+ V'^2/(2 M) + 2U*V' + M U^2
```

Which should be equated to T to find U (ABC formula), unless it gives no solution (negative discriminant), in which option 2) should give a solution.

2) decrease V for a while, eventually *changing the sign* of V, and then increase V until at zero. Drawing a picture gives:

```
C+ V^2/(2 M) - M U^2.
```

equating to T gives U.

You will find that their is a very simple condition which determines whether option 1) or 2) gives a solution.

The case in which initial velocity V'<0 is similar (1 and 2, and maybe some signs, flip). Again, draw a picture in case you get confused.

---

There is some subtle thing here, because if you want to be at T', then T'+K 360 degrees (/2 pi radians) will also do (provided you can go fully round the clock). So you can actually *choose* the *alias* of T that will be easiest to go to.

Comment: To improve the way this looks on screen, you might consider to put a maximum on V itself. Mathematics becomes a bit more involved, but is still manageble.